# passing variables for a variable length argument list in php

Tags: php

I wanted to implement my own debug function that has the same signature as sprintf() function which has a variable arg-list:

```
sprintf('[%s] [%s]', 'textA','textB');  
sprintf('[%s]', 'textC');
```

both above will work.

now I want to has a similar debug function that can pass its own arg-list to sprintf():

```
function debug(A) {
      $msg = sprintf(A);
      ...
}
```

anyone can tell me how can I pass A to sprintf if A is variable length argument.?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function debug() {
      $args = func_get_args();
      $msg = call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/XbleXBMW).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

- http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php
- http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

and

- http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php